# pip install -r requirements.txt failing: does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

Getting an error when build docker image:

```
FROM python:3.9
RUN apt-get update
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY . /tmp/
```

ERROR:

```
file:/// (from -r /tmp/requirements.txt (line 2)) does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found
```

And

```
FROM python:3.9 as base
RUN apt-get update
COPY . /tmp/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
```

Gives the same result

While if I start from Ubuntu as base:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04 as base
ENV TZ=Europe/Moscow
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    python3.9 \
    python3.9-dev \
    python3-pip \
    python3.9-venv \
    python3-psycopg2 \
    git && \
    python3.9 -m pip install pip --upgrade

COPY . /app/ 
RUN ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.9 /usr/bin/python
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update
ENV WORKSPACE /app
```

everything builds fine

but if I copy requirements first

```
COPY requirements.txt /app/ 
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
```

it gives the same error as before:

ERROR:

```
file:/// (from -r /app/requirements.txt (line 2)) does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
```

Comment: Don't you have `.` (or `-e .`, or something else similar) in requirements.txt?

Comment: post first 5 lines of requirements.txt as well.

Comment: Yes, I had `-e .` as first line of autogenerated requirements.txt....thanks!
Now it builds fine.